# Kruskal Wallis from exponential distribution

Tags: r

Generate three samples of size 10 from an exponential distribution with lambda=0.10. Perform the F-test and the Kruskal-Wallis test to see if there are treatment differences in the three groups. Repeat this 1000 times, recording the p-values for both tests. Compare the simulation results by comparing the two histograms made from these p-values.

Here's what I have so far:

```
x<-rexp(10, rate = 0.10)
y<-rexp(10, rate = 0.10)
z<-rexp(10, rate = 0.10)
x
y
z
A=c(x,y,z)
```

This is will generate the random numbers. 
I know that I should have something of the form

```
results <-aov(A~groups, data=A)
summary(results)
```

But this does not work.

Comment: If you are going to post your homework questions here, you should offer more. Where did 'groups' come from for instance? Have you used str() to examine `A`? Is it what you imagined?

Comment: hint: `D=data.frame(value=c(x,y,z),groups=factor(rep(1:3,each=10)))`]

Comment: Ben that was very helpful.
After your hint, I managed to solve all of the question and a similar question too. 
Thank you